Mutex poisoning in C++
does c++ std::mutex get poisoned when a thread holding a lock gets terminated abruptly. If so, how do I recover that mutex in another thread?

What exactly happen that you need to "recover that mutex"? Maybe simply you have some bug in a code?

See the answer in What if a mutex managed by a unique_lock is destroyed?

Threads should not be terminated abruptly in the first place. The only way you can do this is by killing a thread and this you should never do for a lot of reasons.  Other ways where threads terminate abrubtly are usually the consequence of some other UB (access violations), and in that case your program is already broken anyway. So what it your actual (mis)use case?

@PepijnKramer just wanted to know whether a similar functionality exists in C++ like  Rust, which provides a mechanism to recover

The first 2 suggested dupes are about destroying the mutex while it is taken (not about terminating the owning thread). The 3rd suggested dupe is related to threads termination, but does not offer any general asnwer based on the C++ standard, but rather specific info on behavior on POSIX and on Windows systems. Therefore I think the post should not be closed as a duplicate.

From std::mutex documentation:

The behavior of a program is undefined if a mutex is destroyed while
still owned by any threads, or a thread terminates while owning a
mutex.

(emphasis is mine)
This means you are in UB (Undefined Behavior) land, and cannot recover.
A side note:
It's worth noting that the proper solution would not be anyway to recover the mutex, but rather fix the bug that caused the thread to terminate abruptly. This bug probabaly caused some other problems besides the mutex issue.
In any case, once UB ensues, anything can happen and there's no point reasoning about the program behavior (not to mention recovering from it).

In general, use things like std::lock_guard or std::unique_lock to lock mutexes; if a thread really terminates "abruptly", your mutexes are generally not the only problem you're facing, and for anything that's more controlled than that the cleanup will be automatic.

I was thinking of suggesting to replace ", and cannot recover." with just "." but figured that it's actually good information for someone not familiar with the whole concept of UB. +1

Thanks @TedLyngmo. I added that also because the OP specifically asked about recovering.
